# Lambda invoke via SDK is slower than API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have a setup like this:

Browser -> API Gateway -> Lambda: 87 ms

Browser -> Node.js Script -> AWS SDK -> Lambda: 163 ms

If i call the Lambda function via API Gateway then then response time is ok.

If i call the Lambda function via AWS SDK then the response is very slow.

I would like to get rid of API Gateway. Because it is expensive. However, AWS-SDK works very slow.

I use the SDK like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var lambda = new AWS.Lambda({region: "eu-central-1"});
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var url = req.url.split('/');

    var data1 = url[1];
    var data2 = url[2];

    if ( ! data1 || ! data2 ) {
            res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': "application/json" });
            res.end("");
            return;
    }

    var params = {
      FunctionName: 'myfunc',
      InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
      Payload: '{"data1": "' + data1 + '", "data2": "' + data2 + '"}',
      LogType : 'None'
    };
    lambda.invoke(params, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack);
      } else {
            var result = JSON.parse(data.Payload);
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': "application/json" });
            res.end(result.body);
      }
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

How can I call the Lambda function fast?

Comment: Where are the AWS credentials stored for the function that calls lamda.invoke? Finding your credentials takes time.

Comment: @JohnHanley the AWS credentials stored in ~/.aws/credentials. But, aws' documentation says "the credentials should be located in ~/.aws/credentials"

Answer (score 0):

API gateway comes with the CloudFront advantage that's why it will always be faster than invoking the lambda from an external host. 
If you deploy the nodejs script to a lambda in the same region and in the same vpc/subnet (if you have configured), it should be faster compared to API Gateway.